# Storing gps location data in Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I want to build an app like RunKeeper, as detailed in this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/97944/make-app-like-runkeeper-swift-part-1). But I want to save the data in Parse cloud.

I will have a user object, and a user can have multiple runs. I am not sure how to save the gps locations for each run. Since there can be hundreds of locations for each run. Can someone please explain what would be the best/efficient way to save the locations.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Save lat/long pairs as double precision floating point values. That's all there is to it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate where this would be saved. Probably in it's own class (say Location)? Since there would be hundreds of lat/long pairs. And the location class would store a reference to the run id?

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem,

In the user class I would add an array of _runId.

After I would create a class Run with the specific property. So when the user do a run you append the id in the _runId array of the user class.

In the Run class, you could have a property like: location. It should also be an array (_location). So when the user is running you can append to the location array the location of the user for the specific run.

After that you would be able to get all the location of the user with the runId.

Hope this help!

Comment: Parse doc says it is not recommended to use arrays if it will have large (100+) number of data points.

Comment: If you have more than 100 dat maybe could you do multiple object of run in your class Run? with the same ID but different objectID? So if you have more than 100 data, you add a new row to your run. I don't know if it is the best method, but you can try

Answer (score 0):

What if you save all geo data to a JSON file, let's say that each JSON file will be a run, then save the JSON files into your Parse.com.

Good luck.